# Azure Event Hub - Started Receiving Storage Capture Events 2018-06-06?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I have had this event hub up for months.  I have had capture turned on for months.

For some reason today it started receiving events from Blob storage which is configured to capture the Event Hub messages.

These look like event grid messages.

The Event Hub listener started dying from receiving poison messages it was not expecting.

```
[{
  "topic": "/subscriptions/dadsdaddasddsfadsddfdfasdsadfad69f3d24f/resourcegroups/BogusResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/boguseventhub",
  "subject": "bogusservice",
  "eventType": "Microsoft.EventHub.CaptureFileCreated",
  "eventTime": "2018-06-06T22:28:51.4732946Z",
  "id": "dadafdadfasdadfagadsfasd",
  "data": {
    "fileUrl": "https://bogusstorage.blob.core.windows.net/bogusservicebackup/boguseventhub/bogusservice/4/2018/06/06/22/23/51.avro",
    "fileType": "AzureBlockBlob",
    "partitionId": "4",
    "sizeInBytes": 2681,
    "eventCount": 3,
    "firstSequenceNumber": 1308,
    "lastSequenceNumber": 1310,
    "firstEnqueueTime": "2018-06-06T22:28:50.348Z",
    "lastEnqueueTime": "2018-06-06T22:28:51.27Z"
  },
  "dataVersion": "1",
  "metadataVersion": "1"
}]
```

Even stranger, one Event Hub is receiving capture events from 2 event hubs / 2 capture blob containers.

I know I did not configure this.  This one Event Hub is receive capture events from more than 1 capture location / blob container.

Is it possible another person configured this?  Yes that is possible but unlikely.  I don't want to have to delete the entire namespace.

I need to know how to turn this off.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, someone turned on a subscription in the events sections of the Azure Event Hubs Namespace.

I don't who yet.  However, once I deleted the subscription, capture events no longer arrived in the one EventHub.